# Storing API keys and accessing them in commonTest in Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, aws-amplify, kotlin-multiplatform

I am looking for a way to store AWS secrets (Cognito ID and others) to use in my tests. All of the ways I found included third party plugins, like vault from HachiCorp. I haven't found a solution that allows me to easily have them accessible for local testing. I use Github Secrets for my Github Actions. The tests are in commonTest module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [BuildKonfig](https://github.com/yshrsmz/BuildKonfig), since the latest release it allows adding directly values from the gradle file. You can add your values only for test builds using gradle flags.